# stackexchange.com search is down

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, stackexchange.com, 500-server-error

All attempts to do network-wide searches via stackexchange.com ([example](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=meow)) are returning the "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" page:

[image: stackexchange.com error page]

This is a problem, as this is the only way that Charcoal project members and moderators can search the whole network for usage of potential spam domains, terms, etc. outside of one specific site.

Comment: Just acknowledging: we’re aware, thanks.

Comment: Warning: No pandas were harmed or mistreated in the making of this image.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Clearly, they hurt all the other test animals they were gonna use for the photo shoots, because only the panda is featured.

Comment: Functionality should now be restored.

Comment: @JoshZhang seems to be working here; thanks for the quick fix!

Comment: Search down?  Is that a bad thing?

Comment: Yep. We get a lot of spam, some of it pornographic or otherwise illegal by the standards of various international laws. Keeping the place above reproach for the users of various ages and cultures is highly valued. @MartinJames

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thank you for the report, we've identified the culprit and have rolled back the change to restore search functionality.

Comment: [Still broken for `in:saves`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390435/i-cant-search-for-my-saves-in-stackexchange-com)