# I can't search for my Saves in stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, search, stackexchange.com, 500-server-error, saves

I can't find how to access all my saves (saved across all Stack Exchange communities).

Before the migration from Bookmarks to Saves in 2022, all my bookmarks from all communities (sites) used to be listed on the network profile, so there was at least a manageable but cumbersome workaround where you would scroll through all your bookmarks and hopefully find what you're looking for. But that list is now gone with the migration to Saves. Now there is just no way to find a bookmark if you don't know which individual site the bookmark/save you're looking for.

When I try to search for a word using the `in:saves` operator from my network profile, I get the error in the image below.

[image: screenshot of the error below]

> #### Oops! Something Bad Happened!
>
> [image: fail panda]
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.
>
> It's not you, it's us. **This is our fault.**
>
> Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.
>
> Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.
>
> It's not strictly necessary, but if you'd like to give us additional information about this error, do so at our feedback site, https://meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @starball:  It seems that `in:saves` works (now) on each individual site, but not on https://stackexchange.com.

Comment: Also see [I wanted to access a saved question, but I forgot which site it was on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384586/165455).

Comment: As far as I know, it never worked. There is [pending feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315037/cross-site-inbookmarksmine-search) for that.

Comment: Bookmarks from all communities (sites) used to be listed on the network profile, so there was at least a manageable but cumbersome workaround where you would scroll through all your bookmarks and hopefully find what you're looking for. But that list is now gone with the migration to Saves. Now there is just no way if you don't know which individual site the bookmark/Save you're looking for.  I should probably clarify this in the post.

Comment: Well yes, but that is different. The list that used to be on se.com was public, anyone could see anyone else bookmarks, and it didn't let you search it.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry how does that make it different? Being public is a minor detail (doubt too many people care about others seeing what questions they've bookmarked), and you could always search with Ctrl+f.

Comment: @gargoylebident I don't remember what exactly I was referring to by "different", but generally I mean that's not a bug, as it's something that never worked to begin with, we could never really search the favorites/bookmarks in the network profile. The browser's Find function will find only titles, no search inside the posts themselves, and if you have many bookmarks, need to scroll through the pages. Becoming private caused this to be removed because adding a check if the one viewing is you means more development time, that SE did not want to spend money on. (Saved few bucks on that)